# SSRS 2012 expression cauing errors

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

After an upgrade from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2012, one of our reports no longer renders and gives the following error:

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessingException: The specified operation is not valid
```

I've narrowed it down to a textbox with the following expression:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!field1.Value) / (CountDistinct(Fields!field2.Value) - CountDistinct(Fields!field3.Value))
```

Why would this no longer work, and is there an alternative i can use? The text box is to show a percentage and has format P1 assigned to it.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tunrs out that field3 was a calculated field.  I've updated the SQL to populate field3 and all works fine now.